# Android support for the Square Register API?

Tags: square-connect

I am in the in the process of developing point of sale applications for restaurants for both iPhone and Android.  I wanted to use Square to process all the credit card sales seamlessly with my apps, but Square Register API is not available for Android.

Would Square Connect allow my app to integrate in a way where the customer's food order can be taken inside my app, and then Square automatically be launched to allow the customer to pay (pre-populating the dollar amount), and then switch back to my app after the payment is completed?  Based on everything I read, Square Register can do all that (only on iPhone), but Square Connect would not be able to do this.  Am I correct?  Does this mean my apps won't be able to integrate with Square the way I need them to, so I will have to choose a different credit card processor to work with that does have the API functionality I need for both iPhone and Android?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@Stephen Barlow's answer was correct at the time, but this is no longer the case. Square announced the Register SDK for Android on May 25, 2016. Here is the blog post:

https://corner.squareup.com/2016/05/introducing-squares-register-api-for-android.html

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the [Register API](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#navsection-register) is iOS-only. Square currently does not provide a way for an Android application to open the Square Register app to process a payment.