# Mobile Point of Sale (mPOS) Development

Tags: android, payment-gateway, point-of-sale, emv

I am asked to develop a mobile POS android application which will read the Chip Card Data from device (like Square) which can be connected to the audio jack of cellphone. Till now I have successfully done the following:
(1) Detected the device on the audio jack.
(2) Read all the data that is there in the Chip.
(3) Read the tags data/ public keys and certificates which are required for transaction processing.
(I am aware that it is not right/illegal to read this user data - I am not going to store any of this on my device)

I know that the next step would be to integrate my application with a payment gateway.

Working on this, I successfully integrated PAYU Money (a Payemt Gateway) with my android application. It directs me to a "form" where the cardholder needs to fill his information such as NAME, CARD NUMBER, EXPIRY DATE etc.

I have already extracted this data from the EMV chip. But I am unable to send it on THAT form. I don't want my clients to fill any of the data except PIN number to complete the transaction.

I tried to look for other Payment gateways which could directly take the data from my app (Point to Point) but haven't found yet.

Now, I am stuck at what do I do now ? Where do i go from here ? What steps do i follow to get this project done ?

I am also wondering if I am headed to right direction ?

All help or guidance would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Could you please tell me Why the Downvote ?

Comment: Are you using the published REST API, or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K,

You may not be able to do it this way. There are two ways to complete a transaction online :

1. using a webform where you fill in data printed on the credit card : card number, expiration date, cardholder name (which are also accessible by reading the card chip/magnetic track) **AND** cvv number written behind the card (which is NOT available in the chip).
2. using a [POS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_of_sale) application, which will complete an EMV dialog with your card in order to get it to sign and approve the transaction.

It seems you're trying to achieve option 1. Unless someone manually inputs the cvv code, you won't be able to complete the transaction.

However, the mention of a PIN number implies that you want to do an EMV transaction (there's no PIN for webform based transactions). This is a painful process, which will require to use a certified EMV kernel ([or a couple of years to code your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21065242/emv-applicaton-development-questions)), and to get a certification for your application. Most likely not what you're trying to do.

Last option, use the [Square Connect API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31411263/android-support-for-the-square-register-api), whil will take care of the payment processing for you. Unfortunately, you would have to switch to iOS, since it's not supported on Android.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. After the initial struggle I came to similar conclusion. The project that I am working on might get scrapped because I learned that I will also need PCI-PA Compliance for mPOS. Which is a painfully long process. Presently I am trying to achieve SDA for EMV card using mPOS, just to gain understanding about the Authentication process. I have some confusion regarding SDA. I would appreciate if you could take a look at that.

Comment: Not sure I can help much with SDA, but I'll gladly take a look if you point me to your question.